# SSL redirect behaviour

Tags: http, ssl

Scenario:
A.COM, B.COM, C.COM. A & B.COM are registered with SSL. All three sites host entries are in single server in /etc/hosts with respective domain name.

Question:
When I type https://C.COM (non-ssl site). It automatically redirects to A.COM (ssl site).
There is no entries made in DNS (Godaddy) and server host entry for such behaviour.

Can somebody help me understand why is this happening ?

Comment: Can you share which domain goes to what IP on your server.  IE: does a.com and c.com both share IP1 or are they on separate IP addresses?

Comment: All three sites shares single IP and it is redirected on HTTPS port when accessing C.COM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by "registered with SSL". You don't "register" with SSL. I presume you mean you've configured a certificate for HTTPS on the server(s) listening at the address(es) for `a.com` and `b.com`.

Since all 3 domains have entries in `/etc/hosts`, from that machine's point of view, DNS resolution is irrelevant: the `hosts` file will be used to give the client the IP address for each domain.

You're not saying whether `a.com`, `b.com` and/or `c.com` share IP addresses.

When you type `https://c.com` in your browser, it gets the IP address for `c.com` (which presumably is the same as that of `a.com`) and makes an SSL/TLS connection to it (on port 443). It gets the certificate presented by the server (it should show a warning message if you get a certificate that's not valid for `c.com`). The reason you get `a.com` is probably because `a.com` is the default host served on that IP address (and you haven't configured `c.com`).

Comment: One more point to make is that I do not get any warning message when it redirect to C.COM on https from A.COM..

Comment: Perhaps you're using a certificate that's valid for both hosts.